# WCF Service Hosted on IIS 7 Looses Track of CallbackChannel Objects

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have about 50 users of a WPF application that need to have a search routine run when their phone rings.  Part of this solution is have a WCF service that each WPF instance registers with.  The WCF service gets the callback using OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel.  The idea is that when a call is received, the WCF service is notified; identifying the WPF instance and running a search based on the incoming phone number.  This means that the representative does not have to perform a search manually.

The problem is that the service seems to stop working after an unspecified amount of time and I don't know why.  It is hosted on IIS 7.  Is there some setting on IIS that needs to be set?

It's a very simple setup, currently.  Here is the entire code for the service:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class PhoenixCommunicationService : IPhoenixCommunicationService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List of registered Phoenix applications
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly List<PhoenixInstance> _callbackList = new List<PhoenixInstance>();

    private class PhoenixInstance
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Environment { get; set; }
        public IPhoenixCallBack CallBack { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a list of all users logged into a particular environment (DEV, QA, Live)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enviornment">Environment to check</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<string> GetUserList(string enviornment)
    {
        List<string> retVal = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            var userList = _callbackList.Where(l => l.Environment == enviornment).ToList();
            foreach (var user in userList)
            {
                retVal.Add(user.UserName);
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return retVal;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register each Phoenix application
    /// </summary>
    public void RegisterPhoenixUser(string userName, string environment)
    {
        try
        {
            var search = _callbackList.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.UserName, userName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && c.Environment == environment);
            if (search != null)
            {
                _callbackList.Remove(search);
            }
            IPhoenixCallBack callBack = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPhoenixCallBack>();
            _callbackList.Add(new PhoenixInstance
            {
                UserName = userName,
                Environment = environment,
                CallBack = callBack
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
            {
                eventLog.Source = "Application";
                eventLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("PhoenixCommunicationService failed to register user {0}.  {1}", userName, ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Information, 101, 1);
            }
        }
        finally 
        {
            foreach (var pu in _callbackList)
            {
                pu.CallBack.PhoenixUserRegistered(userName, environment);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the application from the Registered List
    /// </summary>
    public void WithdrawRegisteredPhoenixUser()
    {
        string userName = string.Empty;
        string environment = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            IPhoenixCallBack callBack = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPhoenixCallBack>();

            // Remove the application from the list of registered applications
            for (int x = _callbackList.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                var pu = _callbackList[x];
                if (pu.CallBack == callBack)
                {
                    userName = pu.UserName;
                    environment = pu.Environment;
                    _callbackList.RemoveAt(x);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
            {
                eventLog.Source = "Application";
                eventLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("PhoenixCommunicationService failed to withdraw registered user.  {0}", ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Information, 101, 1);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                foreach (var pu in _callbackList)
                {
                    pu.CallBack.PhoenixUserLoggedOff(userName, environment);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the application from the Registered List
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">User to remove</param>
    /// <param name="environment">Environment to remove from</param>
    public void WithdrawRegisteredPhoenixUserName(string userName, string environment)
    {
        try
        {
            // Remove the application from the list of registered applications
            for (int x = _callbackList.Count - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                var pu = _callbackList[x];
                if (string.Equals(pu.UserName, userName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && pu.Environment == environment)
                {
                    userName = pu.UserName;
                    environment = pu.Environment;
                    _callbackList.RemoveAt(x);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
            {
                eventLog.Source = "Application";
                eventLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("PhoenixCommunicationService failed to withdraw registered user {0}. {1}", userName, ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Information, 101, 1);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                foreach (var pu in _callbackList)
                {
                    pu.CallBack.PhoenixUserLoggedOff(userName, environment);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is setup as a single instance.  All the methods work perfectly for a while.  As a matter of fact, the GetUserList() method has never failed.  But I cannot Register new users after some time.

If anyone has suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: I feel the need to add that the event logs are empty.